# Runat server tag causing not a valid identifier error with javascript dynamic input

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to add input of type texts dynamically in javascript after pressing an add button. I want to access these added inputs in code behind vb.net. So i am giving the inputs an ID which is "test" concatenated by a counter. e.g "test" + counter. This is working fine until i add the runat server tag. The error is "'test" + counter + "' is not a valid identifier."

Here is my code below:

```
 $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
 var counter = 1; //initlal text box count
 $(wrapper).append("<input runat='server' id='test" + counter + "' type='text' /><a href='#'+ class='remove_field'>Remove</a>"); //add input box
 counter++; //text box increment
 });
```

Please note that it is working fine whenever i remove the "runat=server" tag

Answer (score 0):

The server doesn't know that the controls exist as you have created them client side. You'll need to code your add button server side and generate your controls there on the postback in vb.

see here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/317515/how-to-dynamically-create-controls-in-asp.net-with-visual-basic-.net